# Kernel threads VS CPU threads

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system, cpu

Is it safe to say CPU core threads and Kernel threads are the same?
I know Kernel threads are created by the Operating system at the Kernel Mode. This question arises from the fact that both CPU core threads and Kernel threads run in privileged environments. So I though maybe they are the same thing.

Is there a case where I can have more Kernel threads than CPU threads?

Comment: What do you mean by "CPU core threads" ? This does no mean anything to me. There are CPU cores and CPU threads (hardware side) on one hand, and user threads and kernel threads on another hand (software side).

Comment: If by CPU thread you mean a hardware thread as in SMT (Symmetric Multi-Threading), aka Logical CPU, then No. The hardware threads are physical executors, like two twin CPUs. There is no privilege level defined for a CPU, the software running in it has privileges. A kernel thread is just an OS thread but in kernel mode.

Comment: A "hardware thread" is just a confusing name for a logical core, aka execution context.  It has nothing to do with software threads or kernel threads.  One physical core may support more than 1 logical core, e.g. via hyperthreading or other SMT.  So it's not at all clear what you're talking about with "CPU core threads" or what you're asking.

Comment: @JérômeRichard ummh, a hyperthreaded core has 2 threads. That's what I am referring to. So there maybe be more Kernel threads all mapped to few CPU threads?

Comment: @Sibulele, The "2 threads" of a hyperthreaded core (a.k.a., "hardware threads") are not at all like the threads in an application program (a.k.a., "software threads.") A hardware thread is a set of registers that are able to hold the [_context_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) of a software thread. Having two "hardware threads" enables a single CPU to concurrently execute the instructions of two software threads without help from the OS.

Comment: P.S.: If a software thread is like an automobile, then a hardware thread is like a lane on a highway in which the automobile can drive. OK, that's kind of a weak anaology, but what I'm trying to say is that a "hardware thread" and a thread in your program don't have much more in common with each other than the lane on the highway has in common with your car.

Comment: @SolomonSlow you explained very well, thank you.  What i am getting from what you are saying is, Kernel Threads (Software Threads) are provided by the OS and they are independent from the Processor threads. The number of Kernel threads can be as many as the OS can provide regardless of how few Processor Threads are.

Comment: @Sibulele, Yes. That's it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I don't know how to credit your answer since it's in the comments. But thank you. I still have a question related to this topic. I will post it